# ASP.net button onserverclick only works when onclick isn't defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, button, onclick

```
    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnNext.InnerHtml = "CLICK";
    }

    <button type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="btnNext_Click" id="btnNext">Next &gt;</button>
```

This works fine, but when I add an onclick event:

```
<button type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="btnNext_Click" onclick="return checkForm();" id="btnNext">Next &gt;</button>
```

And in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function checkForm() {

        if (document.getElementById("<%=lstChooseSpec.ClientID %>").value) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $.jGrowl("<strong>Warning!</strong><br />Please select an item", { sticky: true });
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

It submits the form, but doesn't change the buttons text to 'CLICK'.  The text only changes to 'CLICK' when the onclick() isn't defined, although the form is still submitting!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an <asp:Button> instead of a <button>? An asp button has an OnClick property for server side processing and an OnClientClick property to call javascript when it is clicked.

Comment: Note the difference of an HTML <button> onclick (which is only for JS) vs an <asp:Button> OnClick which is for server-side! They're basically opposites and painful to mix up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this is because when you have both on a button it runs your on click handler followed by the [__doPostBack function](http://aspalliance.com/895) so the onclick would look something like this

`onclick="return checkForm(); __doPostBack('btnNext','')`

So as you can see the __doPostBack, which actually sets up which server function to call, is never called. However, since the button is of type submit, the form is still sent back to the server.

Comment: Note the difference of an HTML <button> onclick (which is only for JS) vs an <asp:Button> OnClick which is for server-side! They're basically opposites and painful to mix up.

Answer (score 9):

try without 'return':
`<button type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="btnNext_Click" onclick="checkForm();" id="btnNext">Next &gt;</button>`

Or if you wanted checkForm() to control whether to post or not - do like this:

```
onclick="if (!checkForm()) return;"
```

Comment: Change the "return" to "return false" and it worked for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onclick="javascript:if (!validaForm()) return false;"
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Front End

```
  <button  id="submit1" runat="server"  
              onclick="if(confirm('Sure?')) { } else{ return false} ;"                       onserverclick="submit_ServerClick"  >save</button>
```

Back End

```
 protected void submit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `LinkButton`:

```
<asp:LinkButton type="submit" runat="server" onserverclick="btnNext_Click" onclick="return checkForm();" id="btnNext">Next &gt;</asp:LinkButton>
```