# how to call onclick event of button tag on server side

Tags: html, asp.net

I am working in aps.net. I have this tag

ASPX file:

```
 <button type="submit" class="login-button" onclick="">Login</button>
```

corresponding .CS file:

```
  protected void login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      /* code */
  }
```

I want to call login_Click event. How can I call this server side event in button tag?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830095/asp-net-button-onserverclick-only-works-when-onclick-isnt-defined

Comment: Laughing at the 4 Close votes because the question is "too broad". Wow, that's a pretty bad fail in the review system.

Answer (score 3):

### Change:

```
<button type="submit" class="login-button" onclick="">Login</button>
```

### To:

```
<asp:Button ID="login" 
            RunAt="server" 
            CssClass="login-button" 
            OnClick="login_Click" 
            Text="Login" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got sume fundamental ASP.NET mix-ups going on.

`<button` is a HTML tag. Any events it triggers must be javascript. Javascript will always be a client-side call. The `onclick` attribute refers to a javascript function.

`<asp:Button` is a ASP.Net  control. It's `OnClick` event will refer to a `C#` method in your code-behind (your `.cs` file) and C# methods are always server-side. `<asp:Button` also has an `OnClientClick` attribute that refers to a javascript method.

**Answer:**

`<asp:Button ID="someControlName" runat="server" CssClass="login-button" OnClick="login_Click"  > Login </asp:Button>` Note that you can also use the shorthand property `Text=""` to combine the closing tag.

**Also, Login control and Membership**

One last thing. I see that you are doing some stuff pertaining to logins? Have you read about ASP.Net's `Login` control specifically for this purpose? There is a lot of information that already exists pertaining to users. You should also look into ASP.Net Membership. There is *a lot* of information for a young ASP.Net developer to learn, but it is definitely worth the trouble.